# Triggering process builder to fire when About Me is changed

Tags: process-builder

In Lightning Process builder, formulas that use `ISCHANGED` to evaluate `AboutMe` on `User` will save, but will not fire their actions.

[image]

This is only the case on User, with this field.  On other objects, `ISCHANGED` in a lightning process formula will fire actions properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by using the 'conditions are met' drop down option.

[image: successful approach]

I was unable to get this to work on user using any combination of formulas.  However, on a custom object, ISCHANGED worked in a formula.

*(clearly its silly of me to type up a formula instead of pointing and clicking)*

Leaving this here in case its helpful for anyone in the future.